# How to derive the form of the posterior for regression?

Tags: probability, bayesian

I have seen the general form of posterior for a regression $y = f(x)$ defined as
$$
  P(\theta|y,x) = \frac{ P(y | x, \theta) P(\theta) }{ P(y|x) }
$$

I would like to know how to arrive at this form, starting from Bayes rule and the laws of probability.

The approach I tried is to write Bayes theorem notated as $p(\theta|v) = \frac{ p(v|\theta) p(\theta) }{ p(v) }$ and then try subsituting something for $v$.

Approach A. With $v \rightarrow y|x$, this gives
$$
  " P(\theta|y|x) = \frac{ P(y|x | \theta) P(\theta) }{ P(y|x) } "
$$
and then if there is a rule that $a|b|c \rightarrow a|b,c$ it gives the result.
However I have not seen such a rule. Does it exist?

Approach B. Start with $v \rightarrow y$ giving
$$
  P(\theta|y) = \frac{ P(y | \theta) P(\theta) }{ P(y) }
$$
and then assume there is a rule that you can condition every factor on some other variable $x$ (see rule below),
giving 
$$
  P(\theta|y,x) = \frac{ P(y | \theta,x) P(\theta|x) }{ P(y|x) }
$$
and lastly assume that $P(\theta|x) = P(\theta)$.
But here I have not seen a rule that allows 
$$
    \text{if}  \quad  p(A) = P(B)P(C)\cdots  \quad\text{then}\quad  p(A|X) = P(B|X)P(C|X)\cdots
$$
Does such a rule exist?

What is the right approach?

Comment: To write that $\nu=y|x$ does not make sense: $y$ is a random variable that has both a marginal distribution (if irrelevant here) and a conditional distribution given the random variable $x$. The notation $P(y|x|\theta)$ does not make sense either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align*}
P(\theta \mid y,x) &= \frac{P(\theta, y,x)}{P(y,x)} \tag{defn. condtl. prob} \\
&= \frac{P(y \mid \theta, x)P(\theta \mid x)P(x)}{P(y \mid x)P(x)} \tag{defn. condtl. prob}\\
&= \frac{P(y \mid \theta, x)P(\theta \mid x)}{P(y \mid x)} \tag{cancellation}\\
&= \frac{ P(y | x, \theta) P(\theta) }{ P(y|x) } \tag{indep.}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

Your initial idea is correct, but you should have used $x,y$ as $v$. Then $p(v)=p(x,y)=p(y|x)p(x)$, and:

$$
p(\theta\vert v)=p(\theta\vert x,y)
=\frac{p(v\vert\theta)p(\theta)}{p(v)}
=\frac{p(y\vert x,\theta)p(x\vert\theta)p(\theta)}{p(y\vert x)p(x)}=\frac{p(y\vert x,\theta)p(\theta)}{p(y\vert x)}
$$

Where we used the fact that $p(x\vert\theta)=p(x)$